# LLDP on Raspberry Pi Zero WH

Tags: raspbian

I can't get lldpd working on Linux raspberrypi 4.14.98.

Using a MicroUSB to RJ-45 converter.

I've installed and started the lldpd package. But when I executen lldpctl no neighborhood information is shown.

Any tips?

Comment: I assume that different computers on the same network show LLDP info just fine, and that the RPi generally has functioning network access (e.g. IP). Is that correct?

Comment: Yes RPi is connected to the network. LLDP info about the RPi can be picked up by other LLDP enabled devices.